# ASP.NET C#, menu class="active" in Site Master page

Tags: c#, asp.net

My project is an asp.net (C#). Menu buttons placed in Site Master page. I'm new on asp.net and c#. Could you help me to How I can add class="active" to menu buttons?

Ex:

```
<ul id="main_menu">
    <li><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a>Recipes</a>
        <ul id="recipes_menu">
            <li><a href="Recipes.aspx">Recipes 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="Recipes.aspx">Recipes 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="Recipes.aspx">Recipes 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="Recipes.aspx">Recipes 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="Recipes.aspx">Recipes 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="Recipes.aspx">Recipes 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="Recipes.aspx">Recipes 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="Recipes.aspx">Recipes 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="Recipes.aspx">Recipes 9</a></li>
            <li><a href="Recipes.aspx">Recipes 10</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="Cooking.aspx">Cooking</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Tip of off-topic: if you're new in asp.net - try learn asp.net mvc

Comment: if you remove 'in Site Master page' from the title and google make html menu item active you will find the answer you seek

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thank you for trying help me to find solution but I solved.
**1.** Just added id for each menu which I want to active,
**2.** Added `window.onload = function ()` to js file,
**3.** Used `window.location.pathname` for get to path of page url,
**4.** Finally, when the page path is `/Default`, JS is adding `class="active"` to `id="home"`.
**5.** Done.
**HTML:**

```
<ul id="main_menu">
        <li><a id="home" href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a>Recipes</a>
            <ul id="recipes_menu">
                <li><a href="Recipes.aspx">Recipes 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="Recipes.aspx">Recipes 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="Recipes.aspx">Recipes 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="Recipes.aspx">Recipes 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="Recipes.aspx">Recipes 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="Recipes.aspx">Recipes 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="Recipes.aspx">Recipes 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="Recipes.aspx">Recipes 8</a></li>
                <li><a href="Recipes.aspx">Recipes 9</a></li>
                <li><a href="Recipes.aspx">Recipes 10</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a id="cooking" href="Cooking.aspx">Cooking</a></li>
        <li><a id="contact" href="Contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

**JS:**

```
window.onload = function () {
    var MenuHome = "/Default";
    var MenuCooking = "/Cooking";

    if (window.location.pathname === MenuHome) {
        document.getElementById("home").className = "active";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("home").className = "";
    }
    if (window.location.pathname === MenuCooking) {
        document.getElementById("cooking").className = "active";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("cooking").className = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have any suggestions, please share with me to fix. Don't just rate my question.

Comment: put a onclick event on each anchor which resets them all and then makes the one you clicked active.... this is then dynamic and doesnt requre hard coding of names.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="active"><a href="Recipes.aspx">Recipes 1</a></li>
```

Comment: I mean how can I add with javascript or c#?

Comment: With jQuery, you can do it. `$("li").addClass("active");`

Answer (score 0):

After your menu add this:

```
var page = (window.location.pathname).split("/");
var len = page.length;
$("li.active").removeClass("active");
$("li>a[href='" + page[len - 1] + "']").parents("li,li.dropdown").addClass("active");
```

`li.dropdown` is for menu which contains a submenu (can be added by adding a dropdown class).

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

In Site.Master name the anchors with your Page class name:

```
<!-- Link to Activity.aspx.cs -->
<li><a id="Activity" runat="server" href="~/Activity">Activity</a></li>
```

...and add your styling, e.g.

```
.active
{
    font-weight:bold !important;
    font-size:110% !important;
    color:white !important;
}
```

In Site.Master.cs Page_Load add:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    Type page = this.Page.GetType();
    System.Web.UI.Control control = FindControl(page.BaseType.Name);
    ((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor)control).Attributes.Remove("class");
    ((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor)control).Attributes.Add("class", "active");
}
```